# Convert pyodbc.Row object into a scalar (e.g., datetime) value?

Tags: python, datetime, pyodbc

I have and Sql server and with handling with pyodbc, the problem is, when I querying the table datetime column the results isn't the format what I looking for, but this:

```
(datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20, 8, 0), )
```

What I like to get is a format like this:

```
2017-03-20 08:00
```

The problem is that I receiving a `'pyodbc.Row'` type. What I like to do is:

1. Converting it to a datetime
2. Alternatively converting it to a string so I can convert the string into a datetime.
3. Or it would be great if could leave all the converting and print out the original result in different format.

At the moment I can convert it to a string, but quite a workaround to picking the date pieces from (datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20, 8, 0), ) string and convert it to datetime.

Comment: Your result is a row. You're only interested in the first element `row[0]` and that is already a datetime object... Please consult the pyodbc documentation on pyodbc.Row or type `help(pyodbc.Row)` in Python

Comment: It's a datetime object in the database but it's a pyodbc.row type in python which is not the same. If I would receive a datetime I wouldnt have to convert to anything

Comment: If you are only retrieving a single value (one row, one column) then you can use `fetchval()` instead of `fetchone()`

Comment: Usually receiving more than one record, I'm using fetchall

Answer (score 0):

pyodbc `.fetchall()` returns a list of pyodbc `Row` objects. So we will get something like this

```py
results = crsr.fetchall()
print(results)
# [(datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0),), (datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 2, 0, 0),)]
```

If we want a list of scalar values (just the `datetime` objects in this case), simply do

```py
results = [row[0] for row in crsr.fetchall()]
print(results)
# [datetime.datetime(2001, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 2, 0, 0)]
```